# elements in XML R

Tags: xml, r

How can i extract the id and the ref value in R, using XML package ? 
I was able to extract the rest of the elements but I am not quite sure how to refer to these 2 values ? 
I want the values `SD_162_13421814` and `SD_162_13421695` in 2 separate variables.

Thank you !!

```
</post>    
    <post id="SD_162_13421814" ref="SD_162_13421695">    
</post>
```

Comment: </post>

-<post id="SD_162_13421814" ref="SD_162_13421695">

<post_score>0</post_score>

</post>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example

```
txt <- '<post id="SD_162_13421814" ref="SD_162_13421695"> <post_score>0</post_score> </post>'
library(XML)
xml <- xmlParse(txt, asText=TRUE)
t(xpathSApply(xml, "//post", xmlAttrs))
#      id                ref              
# [1,] "SD_162_13421814" "SD_162_13421695"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was using xmlValue instead of xmlAttrs.

Comment: You could combine both e.g. by doing `t(xpathSApply(xml, "//post", function(x) c(xmlAttrs(x), score=xmlValue(x))))`.